# In Pandas, how do I compare values in a dataframe with others in its row and column at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe and I would like to be able to compare each value with other values in its row and column at the same time. For example, I have something like this

```
           Col1    Col2    Col3    NumCol
Row1       1       4       7       16
Row2       2       5       8       13 
Row3       3       6       9       30
NumRow     28      14      10
```

For each value that isn't in the NumRow or NumCol, I would like to compare the NumCol and NumRow values in the same column/row as it.

I would like it to return the value of the first instance where NumCol is larger than NumRow in each row.

So the result would be this:

```
Row1       4
Row2       8
Row3       3
```

I have no clue on how to even begin this, but is there a way to do this elegantly without using for loops to loop through the whole dataframe to find these values?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Spend some time with the [Pandas User guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) practicing the examples.

Answer (score 0):

First we flatten the dataframe (here `df` is your original dataframe):

```
df2 = (df.fillna('NumRow')
         .set_index('NumCol')
         .transpose()
         .set_index('NumRow')
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='value')
     )
df2
```

output

```
    NumRow  NumCol  value
0   28      16.0    1
1   28      13.0    2
2   28      30.0    3
3   14      16.0    4
4   14      13.0    5
5   14      30.0    6
6   10      16.0    7
7   10      13.0    8
8   10      30.0    9
```

now for each row of the new dataframe `df2` we have the corresponding number from `NumRow`, corresponding number from `NumCol`, and the number from within the 'body' of the original dataframe `df`

Next we apply the condition, group by `NumCol` and within each group find the first row where the condition is satisfied. We report corresponding `value`:

```
df3 = (df2.assign(cond = df2['NumCol']>df2['NumRow'])
    .groupby('NumCol')
    .apply(lambda d:d[d['cond']].iloc[0])['value']
)
df3.index = df3.index.map(dict(zip(df['NumCol'],df.index)))
df3.sort_index()
```

Output

```
NumCol
Row1    4
Row2    8
Row3    3
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I've been able to reproduce this, but I also get 8 4 3 as my output, when the output should be 4 8 3, since it should be searching by rows. It seems to be sorting the rows in ascending order of NumCol, when I want it to stay in the order of the index.

Comment: @Isaac sorry the order of the elements was getting lost. I updated the answer so that now we keep track of row the element was from. The original answer would have worked if I remembered to add `sort = False` in the `groupby(..)` statement but it is probably cleaner now anyway